# How to reorder child tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm attempting to reorder 2 elements with Javascript so that one appears after the other. I'm using a Wordpress plugin template which is why I can't modify the original template file.

Here is the HTML I am working with:

```
<td class="membership-actions order-actions">
    <a href="#" class="button cancel">Cancel</a> 
    <a href="#" class="button view">View</a>                                 
</td>
```

I want the view button to appear before the cancel button.

Here is the javascript function I created to swap the two a tags, but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
function myscript() {
    $(".view").insertAfter(".cancel");
}
```

Comment: Try switching the order of your selectors maybe. `$(".cancel").insertAfter(".view");`. InsertAfter places the matched elements after the target

Comment: so.... if you insert view after cancel... wouldn't you expect view to come after cancel, the way it already is?

Comment: put another way, if you have the list ['a','b'], and you remove 'b' from the list and insert it back into the list after 'a', the end result would be the same list you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Try out and let me know if it helps.

```js
$(function() {
  let cancelButton = $("a.button.cancel");
  let viewButton = $("a.button.view");
  //cancelButton.insertAfter(viewButton);
  viewButton.insertBefore(cancelButton)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="membership-actions order-actions">
    <a href="#" class="button cancel">Cancel</a> 
    <a href="#" class="button view">View</a>                                 
</td>
```

Comment: I added the jQuery library to the snippet. Try again.

Comment: Why do you need both methods?

Comment: @KevinB When I wrote the code, I was trying to show that insertAfter and insertBefore could be used. Perhaps, I should have explained that in the comment.

Comment: I tried using this and it did not work. Thanks for the try.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos You are right. I didn't noticed that my selector was wrong for the view link.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the selector placement. `$(".view").insertAfter(".cancel")` will insert the `view` link after the `cancel` link, but `$(".cancel").insertAfter(".view")` will insert the `cancel` link after the `view` link.

```js
function myscript() {
    $(".cancel").insertAfter(".view");
}
myscript();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="membership-actions order-actions">
    <a href="#" class="button cancel">Cancel</a> 
    <a href="#" class="button view">View</a>                                 
</td>
```

Comment: Ah just noticed that. I did attempt to use the code you provided and it did not work. I can see your snippet works here. It not working might have to do with Wordpress perhaps.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos Would you consider putting your code in a JSFiddle for me? Just put the minimal amount of code that still produces the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that I could. This is a membership site which is drawing upon a host of files in order to produce the layout in which these two buttons are located. The code you provided if applied to this raw HTML does work. I think it has to do something with how wordpress is loading the buttons.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos Just the minimal amount of code that produces a problem. Try reproducing it if the problem is happening when you are creating elements dynamically.

Comment: Okay let me try and put it in JSFiddle and see if the issue persists in there.